# "ich hab ... für dich" meaning

Tags: meaning

I've met a German friend during these holidays. We didn't see each other during the last month. I told him yesterday that i'm doing a presentation about my internship project tomorrow and that the end of the summer holidays was nice (BBQ, Pizza, fajitas with friends) and I asked how he was doing.

That's what he responded:

> "Hört sich doch jut an! **Joa ich hab morgen eine wichtige Präsentation für dich ich so die letzten zwei Wochen was getan hab**, aber ansonsten läuft hier alles noch entspannt in meiner Schulzeit

I'm not sure about the meaning of the bolded part of the sentence. Does he wish me good luck? Does it mean something like "ich habe für dich gebeten" (I pray for you)?

Or, does it mean that he has a presentation too ?

Comment: "ich habe für dich gebeten" was a supposition. I thought that the quote option was just a way to highlight important things (as if the word QUOTE wasn't clear enough  I probably lost my brain during the night ). I didn't want to cause trouble here. Thank you everyone for your patience and indulgence !

Comment: All in best condition now - we do hope you will continue to have fun with us, learn a bit of German, and bear with us in case we are too picky :) Your assumption that we can highlight things with the quote function is correct. The confusion only arose because it was mixed with a real quote.

Comment: @user34190, don't worry, you are very welcome here!

Comment: @user34190, your friend doesn't seems to like commas: `Joa, ich hab morgen eine wichtige Präsentation, für _die_ ich so die letzten zwei Wochen was getan hab, aber ansonsten läuft hier alles noch entspannt in meiner Schulzeit.`  makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He most likely wanted to say "für **die** ich so die letzten zwei Wochen etwas getan hab"

=> he has a presentation aswell that he worked a lot for.

Apart from that, if he were to say "**ich habe** eine Präsentation **für dich**"

=> It would simply mean that he has a presentation for you - this could mean that he wants you to hold one he prepared, or that he wants you to watch one.

Comment: "für die ich" were the right words! Thank you!

Comment: *für dich ich* is a typical autocorrect failure in text messages